# Collison Not working with an empty object (unity)

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I wrote a Script which creates a array of gameobjects
I added the rigidbody and boxcollider to the gameobjects.

I created an empty object and added the Script.

Unfortnetley the collison wont be detected.

If i add the Script e.g to my player then it works.

The code of the script of my gameobjects with the array:

```
for(int i= 0; i < rain.Length; i++){
 rain[i] = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
rain[i].name = "rain" + i;
rain[i].AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
rain[i].AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
rain[i].transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0,15, 0);           
}
```

what i want to reach is. I have a floor which contains my character.
As the (gameobjects) are falling and collide with the floor the should respawn....

but with the method onCollsionEnter(....); the method just refers to the empty object and not the individual gameobjects which I created.

Comment: welcome to SO. If you show the code you have it will be more likely that someone can help out

Comment: Hi, thanks. I posted my code. I hope it will help you to understand my problem.

Comment: ok i just solved it. :)

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer that users can see it in future

Answer (score 1):

What object did you attach the OnCollisionEnter script to?
I have attached  OnCollisionEnter script to the plane, and it is just working fine.

[image]

I added this collision script to plane:
[image: I added this collision script to plane]

Just like you, I attached this script to an empty gameobject:
[image: Just like you, I attached this script to an empty gameobject]

It would be helpful if you could clarify your question if I misunderstood it